# Reversing the direction of a CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following animation. It works beautifully moving from right to left, but I need to make it go left to right - and the text needs to start fully filling the space (no big gap to start with). I've been messing around with this for ages, trying different things and getting nowhere - any suggestions on what to do to reverse it?

```css
.scrolling-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  animation: marquee 80s linear infinite;
}

.item-collection-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  animation: swap 80s linear infinite;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #00E4A2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.item::after {
  content: '•';
  position: relative;
  right: -17px;
}


/* Transition */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}

@keyframes swap {
  0%,
  50% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50.01%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-text">
  <div class="ticker">
    <span class="item-collection-1">
                      <span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span>
    <span
      class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span>
      <span
        class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span>        </span>
        <span class="item-collection-2">
                      <span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span>
        <span
          class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span>
          <span
            class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span><span class="item">Some Text Here</span>            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer elsewhere - all that was needed was to add "reverse" to the animations:

```
.ticker {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  animation: marquee 80s linear reverse infinite;
}

.item-collection-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  animation: swap 80s linear reverse infinite;
}
```